# what is better to use php query set or mysql function?

Tags: php, mysql

If you had data in table 1 that you need to use to return data in table 2 for each row returned in table 1. What is more efficient to use a set of querys in PHP one inbedded in the while loop of the other or an SQL function within a query?

for example:

```
$qry = mysql_query(SELECT date FROM table1)

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
  $qry = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE date=$res['date']")
}
```

or to do this as a function that returns the Id from table1 within the query.

Comment: You lost me there. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: That is correct I cannot join as I am also manipulating the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on if the data is easier to find during the while loop or in the query itself.

So if the DB has to base the sub-query on the result of each row in the main query, and there are 1000 total rows and 100 results in the main query, it has to check all of the rows 100 times, so that's 100,000 sub-queries it runs.

So think it terms of the number of results of the main query. If your while loop has to query the DB 100 times while the DB can do it much faster and efficiently in one query, that's better. But if you want a subset of answers that you can say 'query only based on the last set of results' the while loop is better.

Answer (score 3):

A (LEFT / RIGHT) JOIN?

Unless I've misunderstood the question...

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) sql syntax. If you have 2 tables: messages and author and you want to return messages with authors. Then you can write following SQL statement:

```
SELECT m.body, a.name FROM message m 
LEFT JOIN author a ON (a.id=m.author_id)
```

This will return message body with corresponding author name

Table author:

- id - primary key
- name - name of the author

Table message:

- body - text of the message
- author_id - id of the author

**UPD1:**

This will be faster then looping each message and select an author. Because `JOIN` allows you to return all data in **single** query (not N x queries when using `for` loop).

**UPD2:**

With your tables the query will look like:

```
SELECT t1.date, t2.name FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.date=t1.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

What is more efficient to use

> a set of querys in PHP one inbedded in the while loop of the other

or

> an SQL function within a query

Seems you answered your question yourself, didn't you?

Every query you send to the dbms has to be sent over the network, parsed, analyzed then executed. You may want to minimize the number of queries sent to the db.

There may be exceptions, for example if the processing of the data requires operations which the dbms is not capable of.

Comment: It is almost always faster to perform a join than to return data and perform one additional query for every row returned previously.

Comment: +1 This answer seems fine to me.  If you are creating table2 in the database and everything needed is in table1 and the DBMS is capable of doing the job, then why involve PHP?  The only caveat is that you don't mention the data volumes so it sounds a bit like suspiciously premature optimization - if there are only a small number of rows then either method will be fine performance-wise and you need to optimize for something else - ease of development and maintainability.